# Data sanitisation question - regular expression for removing combinations of trailing spaces and commas

Tags: regular-expression, data

I have address strings which were (due to poor initial programming) allowed far too much entry of free text. In the course of cleaning up this inherited mess, I have noticed that at the end of the address fields, there are frequently (and frequently not) commmas which I want to get rid of.

The problem is that (again, frequently!) those inputting the data (paid by the line...) input strings like:

```
`address_1_string  ,  `
```

That's address_1_string followed by two spaces followed by the comma I wish to delete, followed by two more spaces. The number of spaces (either before or after the comma) is arbitrary, typically going from 0 - 5. The problem is further compounded by the fact that `address_string_1` itself may have internal (valid) commas.

So, what I am looking for is a regular expression that goes to the end of the line, deletes any trailing spaces, the first comma and then any more spaces until a valid [a-zA-Z0-9] ([:alphanum:]?) character is found.

I have notions of regular expressions, but this is above my pay grade. This is my first post on Stackexchange, so if I'm in the wrong place, please redirect me. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
< input sed 's/[[:space:],]*$//' > output
```

Would delete all the spacing and comma characters at the end of the line.

To edit the file in place, some `sed` implementations have a `-i` option inspired from `perl`'s `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:],]*$//' input-and-output    # GNU, busybox, NetBSD, OpenBSD
sed -i '' 's/[[:space:],]*$//' input-and-output # FreeBSD, macOS
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a question: I thought `sed` worked something like this `sed -i 's/[[:space:],]*$//g' > file.txt` - I thought the substitution had to have a blank `//` specified at the end of the pattern? The `i` inplace is superfluous here - I've started to use it less, after a few bloopers! understood the rest of your regexp. Merci!

Comment: @PHB, sorry typo, my bad. Fixed now. No need for `g` as there can only be one match per line.

Comment: Ah, OK, so the /g refers to a per-line substitution rather than file-level? And there was me thinking that it was on file-level all this time. `sed` works on a line-level by default - OK, that's cool. Learnt something today! Merci encore!... Can't mark as correct - not enough rep, but have marked as helpful. Will come back when I have rep!